# Pass data from ajax success to outside else/if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm having an issue taking the appropriate result from my ajax success function and passing it to an external function to be used.

I'm currently taking user input to query a data source via ajax and returning the object, which works fine. I'm appending the results to an option list which is also working. However, when I click the object, I want to pass data associated with that object to the following line in my if/else outside of my ajax call:

```
$("#groupName").val(result[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.name);
```

So my options are correct, and when I click an option it reflects the clicked option in the console. The issue is that I'm not passing the result into my `else if` correctly, apparently.

The heirarchy of my _source is correct but I just don't know how I need to change my .val argument in order to pull the right value.

Any ideas?

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function () {
  let _this = $(this);
  let foundOption;
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;
  if (_this.val() === '') {
    return;
  } else if ((foundOption = $('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector)).length) {
    console.log(optSelector); //this prints the option[value] of the clicked value as it should
    $("#groupName").val(result[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.name);
    $("#groupNum").val(result[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.code);
  } else {

    const searchResult = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
      data: {
        search_result:searchResult
      },
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      type: "POST", 
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        console.log(searchResult);
        $("#returnedProducts").empty();

        let result = response.hits.hits;

        console.log(result);
        for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          $("#returnedProducts").append("<option srindex=" + [i] + " value=" + result[i]._source.name + ">" + result[i]._source.name + "</option>");


        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

my object looks like this

```
hits
  hits
    _source
      name
      code
```

Comment: How do you click on a object? DO you mean to select an option from dropdown?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant when object is selected

Comment: @brk but when I select one it says it's undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach set the value of the `input#groupName` to `_this.val()`.
Also note `(foundOption = $('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector)).length` this snippet is not making any conditional check but just assigning a value

```js
$('#productInput').on('input', function() {
  let _this = $(this);
  let foundOption;
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;
  if (_this.val() === '') {
    return;
  } else if ($('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector).length) {
    $("#groupName").val(_this.val());
  } else {

    const searchResult = $(this).val();
    $("#returnedProducts").empty();
    var result = [{
      _source: {
        "name": "cat",
      },

    }, {
      _source: {
        "name": "cat1",
      },

    }, {
      _source: {
        "name": "cat2",
      },

    }, {
      _source: {
        "name": "cat33",
      },

    }];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      $("#returnedProducts").append("<option srindex=" + [i] + " value=" + result[i]._source.name + ">" + result[i]._source.name + "</option>");

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="productInput" list="returnedProducts">
<datalist id="returnedProducts"></datalist>
<input id="groupName">
```

Comment: So this all takes place inside my input function which is tied to the datalist so I haven't needed to use on change. Does that sound right?

Comment: So couldn't I just use your first suggestion by itself and then change the '.find' to use data?

Comment: `change` handler can be kept outside `input` otherwise it will attach event every time. Also look for event delegation

Comment: I can help more if there is a demo :)

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll have to try this. http://jsfiddle.net/qhbt569o/8 is closest demo I have but it is using a variable for result, where my result comes from ajax. If that makes sense

Comment: So the fiddle works but only because I declare 'result' globally there

Comment: I see your edit above now. Will this still work for me since my 'result' is set within an ajax success function?

Comment: I have put the result inside the `else` block

Comment: Ah ok. Will that work the same as being inside a success function?

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! This works but I have a crazy question: What if there's another value under _source or _source.name that I want to put into another input even if it's not in the option value?

Comment: get the `selectedIndex` and retrieve the value from the array

Comment: Ok so instead of  ```$("#groupName").val(_this.val());``` I would do  ```$("#groupName").val('srindex[i]'._source.attribute;``` ?

Comment: I'm still confused on that part, sorry. Can you help clarify that please? That will totally solve this issue